# Domain of the adjoint operator of a bounded operator (on a Hilbert space). (Experimental physicist)

Tags: operator-theory, adjoint-operators

Let $A$ be a bounded operator on a Hilbert space $H$ and $D_A$ its domain. We can define the following functional on $D_A$: $$f_\eta(\xi)=(\eta,A\xi).$$
Then we have that: $$||f_\eta(\xi)||=||(\eta,A\xi)||≤||\eta||⋅||A\xi||<\infty.$$
So $f_\eta$ is a bounded functional and hence it's continuous on its domain. Now we can use Riesz' theorem to say that:$$\exists! f^\eta: (f^\eta,\xi)=f_\eta(\xi)=(\eta,A\xi).$$
We define adjoint of $A$ the operator $A^♱$ such that: $$A^♱(\eta)=f^\eta.$$ My first question is: since $f_\eta$ is continuos for every $\eta$, and hence Riesz' theorem holds for every $\eta$ in $H$, can we say that the domain of $A^♱$ can be $H$ itself?

If this is the case, why can't we say that, if $(A,D_A)$ is symmetric, and hence bounded, we can always restrict $D_A^♱=H$ to $D_A$ so that $A $ is also self-adjoint?

I will add an example of my problem. Let $H=L_2([0,1])$ with $\mu(dx)=dx$. Let's consider: $$\hat{p}=-i\frac{d}{dx}.$$
$\hat{p}$ is symmetric when: $$D_A=\{ \psi \in L_2([0,1]): \psi \,\,\text{absolutely continuous}, \psi'\in L_2([0,1]), \psi(0)=\psi(1)=0 \}.$$
Lecturer told us that this operator is not self adjoint beacause the domain of $A^♱$ is:
$$D_A^♱= \{ \psi \in L_2([0,1]): \psi \, \,\text{absolutely continuous}, \psi'\in L_2([0,1])\}$$ But this contraddicts what I thought was true: that $D_A^♱=H$.

Comment: But is $\hat p$ bounded...!?

Comment: I think it is since in the specified domain it is symmetric... Thank you for your answer

Comment: symmetric is not the same as bounded.

Comment: Usually, the momentum operator is not bounded I think

Comment: I thought I proved that every symmetric operator has norm 1, BUT I DIDN'T so everything is okay thank you for your help you saved me !

Comment: Yes. Note that self-adjoint operators are symmetric (the converse is false in general), and there are unbounded self-adjoint operators (and thus unbounded but symmetric operators), e.g. the "position operator" on $L^2(\mathbb R)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domain of the adjoint is not $H$ in general. It is restricted by the existence of the vector in Riesz's lemma in the following way
$$D_{A^\dagger}=\{\psi \in H  |  \exists \eta \in H :\forall v \in D_A, \langle \psi, Av \rangle= \langle \eta, v \rangle \}$$
That is, not everywhere in $H$ does there exist such an $\eta$.

**EDIT:**

I had ignored the boundedness of the operator in question. Yes, because the operator $A$ is densely defined by continuity one may prove the domain of the adjoint is the entire space. As for your second question, that's exactly right, a bounded symmetric operator is self-adjoint because it coincides with the restriction of the adjoint to its (the operator's) domain

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In the case of a bounded operator, isn't it true that the lemma guarantees us that for every $\psi$ in $H$ such vector exists?

Comment: @davise you're right, I missed that detail in your question!

Comment: "As for your second question, that's exactly right, a bounded symmetric operator is self-adjoint because it coincides with the restriction of the adjoint to its (the operator's) domain" - what do you mean here, exactly? Yes, bounded symmetric operators are self-adjoint. But nowhere you have to restrict any operator/domain.

Comment: @Jakob I mean that if $(A, D_A)$ is a bounded symmetric operator, then it is self adjoint because it coincides with $(A^\dagger, D_A)$. The restriction I was talking about is from $H$ to $D_A$

Comment: If you restrict the domain of the adjoint operator, you are not talking anymore about the adjoint operator... So if you say that for a bounded operator $A$ defined on a (dense) domain $D_A$ you have that $D_{A^\dagger}$ (the domain of the adjoint) is the whole Hilbert space $H$, i.e. $ D_{A^\dagger}=H$, then the adjoint operator is $(A^\dagger,D_{A^\dagger})$ - if you now change the domain you are not talking about the adjoint anymore!

Comment: @Jakob Fine, I'm talking about the restriction of the adjoint operator, which means strictly speaking they're not equal, is that your point? Then what does one usually do, extend $A$ by continuity to the entire space?

Comment: But for bounded (and densely defined) operators $A$ you can make use of the BLT theorem and uniquely extend $A$ to the whole Hilbert space $H$.

Comment: @Jakob if you extend $A$ to $H$ then you're not really talking about $A$ anymore either so I don't think this is much different

Comment: Why do you react annoyed?... Yes, the starting point is that you first extend $A$ and then talk about its adjoint. In basically all texts on QM that I know, bounded operators are always meant to be defined on the whole space. And it **is** different: If you want to prove that an operator is self-adjoint, you need $A=A^\dagger$ and $D(A)=D(A^\dagger)$, where both $A^\dagger$ and $D(A^\dagger)$ have a precise meaning! Of course you are free to restrict $A^\dagger$ to a smaller domain, but then this restriction is not the adjoint and you cannot speak of self-adjointness!

Comment: Thank you guys for helping me everything is way more clear now.